# Javascript: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs

I'm reading a text file and converting it to JSON format using regex in my react project.It is working fine but when including in my code it is giving 
    TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
There is some problem while performing replace but I am unable to understand the problem. Please help me out in resolving this issue.

I think the problem is `allText = allText.replace(/\s{2,}|\n+/g, " ");` is not getting completed.

Comment: Can you provide an example text file?

Comment: So start adding some console.log lines and figure out why you got something in an index that is not defined

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jn3aljptn512ags/tweet.txt?dl=0

Comment: ...text.match(/.+(?=\s\w+\s$|\s\w+$)|\w+\s$|\w+$/g)]) remove `...` in `text.match` method

Comment: it probably returns `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.match(regex)` returns `null` if there are no matches and will cause an error when trying to perform the spread operation.

you could use `[...text.match(regex)||[]]` but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't think it would make sense in your coding style, personally I would break it up a bit more so it's readable. I.e., put `text.matches(regex)` into a meaningful variable name. Like what the heck is your regex doing, anyways? haha

Comment: I'll do the cleanup in the end. Write now trying to convert a text file to JSON format

Comment: Is there anyway I can ignore null values while mapping it?

Comment: null values where?

Comment: When am mapping it, it is returning                                                         
{date: "2014-06-01 23:07:58", text: undefined, user_id: undefined}
{date: "2014-06-01 23:48:06", text: "President Resigns in Georgia’s Breakaway Region of Abkhazia t.co/DAploRvCvV", user_id: "nytimes "}         but I don't want those 2 undefined values

Comment: I want text value and user_id from 2nd result in the first one

Comment: How can I throw it away?

Comment: `[null].filter(e=>e!==null)`

Comment: I'm not sure you can do the other thing I was mentioning, so I removed that comment.

Comment: Sorry am new to js and trying to learn it, can you please tell me where to use this in that map function>

Comment: `.map((text, index) =>
                            [dates[index], ...text.match(/.+(?=\s\w+\s$|\s\w+$)|\w+\s$|\w+$/g)]).filter(e=>((typeof e.text!=="undefined)&&(typeof e.user_id!=="undefined")))
                        .map(([date, text, user_id]) => ({date, text, user_id}));`

Comment: Getting error on filter "name contains both ascii and non ascii characters" and console is showing this error message "SyntaxError: Unexpected character '​' (49:32)" which is ".filter‌​(e=>"